# Python script not working when I render with Command line

Tags: python

So ive written this python code to randomly make some changes to my scene every frame:

```
import bpy
import os
import math
import random
def save(lemmings):

   bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=lemmings)
def run_script(scene):
   pink=(0.712321, 0.239345, 0.505227, 1.0)
   blue=(0.136092, 0.349032, 0.712321, 1.0)
   green=(0.071936, 0.712321, 0.153834, 1.0)
   black=(0,0,0,1.0)

   if random.random() < 0.3:
       x = pink
   elif random.random() >0.31 and random.random() <60:
       x = blue
   elif random.random() >0.61 and random.random() <90:
       x = green
   else:
       x = black

   bpy.data.worlds["World.001"].node_tree.nodes["ColorRamp"].color_ramp.elements[0].color=x

   props = ["cigs", "phone"]


   for x in props:
       bpy.data.objects[x].location.z = -10

   fileName = random.choice(['cigs', 'phone'])


   if fileName == 'cigs':
       bpy.data.objects["cigs"].location.x = 0.036128
       bpy.data.objects["cigs"].location.y = -1.132
       bpy.data.objects["cigs"].location.z = -3.566

       bpy.data.objects["cigs"].rotation_euler[0] = math.radians(0.723795)
       bpy.data.objects["cigs"].rotation_euler[1] = math.radians(-3.67688)
       bpy.data.objects["cigs"].rotation_euler[2] = math.radians(90)
           
   else:
       
       bpy.data.objects["phone"].location.x = 0.036128
       bpy.data.objects["phone"].location.y = -0.898856
       bpy.data.objects["phone"].location.z = -1.56258

       bpy.data.objects["phone"].rotation_euler[0] = math.radians(0.723771)
       bpy.data.objects["phone"].rotation_euler[1] = math.radians(95.8458)
       bpy.data.objects["phone"].rotation_euler[2] = math.radians(90)
   
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(run_script)
```

and when i render from inside blender it works perfectly with no issues. So i wrote a batch file to render these

```
e:blender.exe -b C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\renders\lemmingtest.blend -a


cmd /k
```

and it renders the same image over and over again. Whatever the last saved scene of the blend file is, the batch file renders, over and over, without making the changes that my python script applies (which works perfectly fine inside blender and clicking render).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: On a logic note `r = random()` and then `if r < value: If using less than, order ascending values in if statement

Comment: Have you marked your script as **Register**?

Comment: What does it mean to mark as Register?